# sparksession getorcreate method stuck till other spark job is running

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I'm trying to run spark job from oozie and I have two action in oozie workflow and they are running parallely. However when Oozie started one other is stuck till one is completed at the sparksession.getorcreate() method.

```
self.spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(appName).config(conf=conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run on YARN - open Resource Manager UI and check if there is enough resources for all the jobs (e.g. vCores/Memory).